# Git repository inside another git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following directories structure:

> - g1/
>
>   - .git
>   - a
>   - b
>   - **c/**
>
>     - **.git**
>     - **d**
>     - **e**

As you can see, I have de repository "c" inside repository "g1". When I use the following command:

`git clone g1 g2`

I only get the following directories structure:

> - g1/
>
>   - .git
>   - a
>   - b
>   - **c/**

The directory "c" remains empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Submodules](http://web.archive.org/web/20090302072040/http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) (discussed in the [Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)), helps manage repositories nested within a main repository:

> Submodules allow foreign repositories
>   to be embedded within a dedicated
>   subdirectory of the source tree,
>   always pointed at a particular commit.
>
> They are not to be confused with
>   remotes, which are meant mainly for
>   branches of the same project;
>   submodules are meant for different
>   projects you would like to make part
>   of your source tree, while the history
>   of the two projects still stays
>   completely independent and you cannot
>   modify the contents of the submodule
>   from within the main project.
>
> Submodules maintain their own
>   identity; the submodule support just
>   stores the submodule repository
>   location and commit ID, so other
>   developers who clone the superproject
>   can easily clone all the submodules at
>   the same revision.

Comment: Right, and after cloning the repository you would run `git submodule update` to populate the submodules.

Comment: Updated link to the documentation: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules .
And the manual page: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule .

Answer (score 3):

Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will be a bit more precise in how it present submodule.
Since a submodule is registered as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([a special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)), that explains why '`c`' is empty when the parent repo is cloned.
See also "[`git submodule` checks out the same commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30343691/6309)".
You need a `git submodule update --init` to fill-up '`c`'.

That is now more clearly documented.

See [commit ec48a76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec48a76306091abfa7831a97f36949ab82432ddc) (27 May 2015) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7df5c97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7df5c978d579b83f23d8711b751ab2cd0f326af5), 11 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `submodule` doc: reorder introductory paragraphs
>
> It's better to start the man page with a description of what
>   submodules actually are, instead of saying what they are not.

The [`git submodule` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec48a76306091abfa7831a97f36949ab82432ddc/Documentation/git-submodule.txt) now (June 2015) starts with:

> A submodule allows you to keep another Git repository in a subdirectory
>   of your repository.
>   The other repository has its own history, which does not interfere with the history of the current repository.
>   This can be used to have external dependencies such as third party libraries for example.
>
> **When cloning or pulling a repository containing submodules however,
>   these will not be checked out by default; the '`init`' and '`update`'
>   subcommands will maintain submodules checked out and at
>   appropriate revision in your working tree**.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is storing git repository as a [bare](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---bare) repository inside another git repository.

This approach will be helpful when you don't control the git flow for using `inner` git repository. For instance, if 3rd party tool uses it. In that case it may try to clone inner repository given a path to it.

I documented the commands for [storing git repository inside another git repository](https://rokpoto.com/git-repository-in-another-git-repository/) as a bare repository.