# Git submodule fail because of link to unexisting revision

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I've got a problem with git submodules pull: I have two reporistories, let's call them repo A and repo B.

Repo B is a submodule of repo A, so I added repo B as a submodule of A with this command line:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:Aracthor/B.git libvvgl
```

But when I try to clone my project like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:Aracthor/A.git
```

My B project folder is empty and when I try this (solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)):

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:Aracthor/A.git
```

My B folder contains only an empty file `.git`, that contains itself an only line:

> ../.git/modules/B/

That is a path to a folder with some git data, but still not my B repository files.

I already tried this too:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And nothing changes.

When I Looked at my Github repositories ([Here for A](https://github.com/Aracthor/octo-planet/tree/master) and [Here for B included](https://github.com/Aracthor/libvvgl/tree/master)) I've noticed something strange: A repository is linking its submodule to a revision key (32a0a80f17ee3628cb99b886c68e566981d7deff) that doesn't exist on any commit on B repository, and that lead to a 404 when clicked on Github.

So from here, it looks like a Github bug... But I would prefer your solutions rather than accuse this plateform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means A has recorded a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) referencing a SHA1 of the [submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30854263/6309) `B` which was never pushed to GitHub.

When `A` used `B` in a local clone, `B` was at `32a0a80`. `A` was pushed, but `B` was not. Hence the issue.

Normally, a `git submodule update --init` would populate `B` with files from commit `32a0a80`, but since that commit was not pushed, that command would fail as well.

Comment: Finally, thanks to your links (and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule/1260982#1260982) I finally deleted my submodule to create a new one, linked to the good version. Thanks a lot!