# Creating new Git repo in sub-folder's of git with existing source code

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I'm using shared hosting and I have several website hosted into same server as an addon domain. Now I want to use git for version control

Say I have 3 website as *`example1.com`*, *`example2.com`* & *`example2.com`*. *`example1.com`* is hosted as main domain in `public_html/`

My dir structure is

```
/public_html/
  .git/
  .gitignore
  index.html
  .....

  example2.com/
    index.html
    .....

  example3.com/
    index.html
    .....
```

`.gitignore` content of *`example1.com`* is

```
*.log
log/*
tmp/*
.env
/example2.com/
/example3.com/
```

Now my question is as I already have a git repo in `public_html` so how can I initilized a new repo with existing code of *`example2.com`*

I create a new project in gitlab as *example2* (*`git@gitlab.com:myusername/example2.git`*) now I'm want to push code of 
example2.com dir into this repo.

I checked some example as how to achieve this, so I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456888/5019802) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/84533/70357). So I tried below cmd from `public_html`.

```
git submodule add https://gitlab.com/myusername/example2.git example2.com
```

But I'm getting below error

> ```
> The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
> example2.com
> Use -f if you really want to add it.
> ```

If I remove `example2.com` from root `.gitignore` then it'll add the code in to my example1.com repo. I'm too confused as how to maintain separate commit/repo for sub-folder

Can anyone help me with there knowledge.

Thanks in advance.